# How can I pass the Id from Login method in Account Controller in ASP.Net MVC Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, parameter-passing

I've been working on an **ASP.Net MVC** application based within a **.NET Entity Framework.** Within it I set the authentication to **individual User Account**s to allow a **Login/Register** process to occur on the application.

As you know when a user registers on the application they are added into the **ASPNetUsers** table with a unique id generated which is used to identify the user.

**ASPNetUsers Columns and Datatypes**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
[Id]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[Email]                NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
[EmailConfirmed]       BIT            NOT NULL,
[PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT            NOT NULL,
[TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT            NOT NULL,
[LockoutEndDateUtc]    DATETIME       NULL,
[LockoutEnabled]       BIT            NOT NULL,
[AccessFailedCount]    INT            NOT NULL,
[UserName]             NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

**ASPNetUsers id data**

[image: ASPNetUsers id data]

The methods for the login and register function are all located within the **Account Controller**. In the Account Controller I did an initial process which took the id generated for the user when they register.

**Register function in AccountController**

As you can see the Id is passed from the register function using a RedirectToAction. It's important to note the RedirectToAction is used after the id is defined within the code by the **UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");**

The RedirectToAction method passes the id forward to my **AddNAA_Profile** method defined in a separate controller called **NAAProfileController**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("AddNAA_Profile",  new { UserId = user.Id, Controller = "NAAAdmin" });
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

**AddNAA_Profile Method in NAAAdminController**

In the AddNAA_profile GET method the UserId is set up to display the id within the view so the user can create a profile with an userid which can be used to associate them to the specific profile.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddNAA_Profile(string UserId)
    {
        ViewBag.User_ID = UserId;
        return View();
    }
```

**AddNAA_Profile View after user clicks Register**

[image]

So now you know how I did the register function I wanted to get your professional opinion on how I can proceed to do some similar type of conditioning with user Logins.

You see in the case of a Login I'm not sure how to carry the id as I did with the Register function. As in the register function the id is generated inside the method, but it's not the same case here.

**Login Method in Account Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);



            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.If you do not have an account please register one");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

I was told by lecturer that the user.id is pulled in this method on the **Case SigninStatus.Success;** line.

However when I tried to implement the same type of RedirectToAction process I kept getting an error where it said ***"the name user doesn't exist in this context"***

```
   var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, 
   model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToAction("GetNAA_Profile2", new { UserId = user.Id, Controller = "NAAAdmin" }); 

            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.If you do not have an account please register one");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

You see what I'm trying to do is pass the id from the login into my GetNAA_Profile2 method which checks for the respective profile linking with the id passed through

**GetNAA_Profile2 method in Profile Controller**

```
   public ActionResult GetNAA_Profile2(string UserId)
    {
        return View(_NAAService.GetNAA_Profile2(UserId));
    }
```

The GetNAA_Profile2 method works properly with the UserId I defined in my RouteConfig file. I just need to work on a means of sending the id to the method from the login.

So the main question is how do I take the id from the Login method and pass it into the GetNAA_Profile2 method?

**Update [07/03/2018]**

I've tried implementing the lines

```
ApplicationUser CurrentUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
```

and

```
var GUID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

But despite this, the values returned from these lines always remain NULL.

Comment: Not really a question, have you tried SO Code Review?

Comment: The question is how to take the id from the Login method and pass it to the GetNAA_Profile 2 method. Sorry I should have made that a bit clearer. And no what is SO Code Review?

Comment: Can you confirm that the UserId is coming back from result in this line: var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

Comment: My apologies. It's not that line, i've edited it to reflect the proper line, it's within the register method where it says `UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");`

Comment: Please post the register method

Comment: The register post method is in the main post, underneath Register Function in Account Controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166361/discussion-between-kevin-raffay-and-henry-green).

Answer (score 0):

Inside your switch function use the following code for success

```
     switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:

      ApplicationUser CurrentUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
//Use this "CurrentUser" Id for your function.

        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.If you do not have an account please register one");
            return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: So with this in place, how can I pass the id using a RedirectToAction?  I tried implementing the same line `return RedirectToAction("GetNAA_Profile2", new { UserId = user.Id, Controller = "NAAAdmin" });` but it still doesn't like the `user.id` section.

Comment: Use CurrentUser.id in place of user.Id

Comment: As for your redirect function 
return RedirectToAction("GetNAA_Profile2", "NAAAdmin",new { UserId = CurrentUser.Id });

Comment: I'm getting an error back now, it's telling me `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` in reference to the `RedirectToAction("GetNAA_Profile2", "NAAAdmin",new { UserId = CurrentUser.Id });` line of code

Comment: Do you have a view by the name of GetNAA_Profile2 beacuse the code will redirect you to the view.
ActionResult is not a function in case of HTTPGET, you have to associate a view with it.

Comment: Yes the view is there. This is the method it's pushing to within that specific controller `public ActionResult GetNAA_Profile2(string UserId)
        {

            return View(_NAAService.GetNAA_Profile2(UserId));


        }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166375/discussion-between-henry-green-and-avinash).

Comment: did you tried debugging put a breakpoint on success and see if the controls reach there, because i use the same code to get current users id while logging into the application.

Another approach to find current users ID would be 

var GUID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

This GUID Will be the aspnetusers ID that was generated while user registered.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried debugging put a breakpoint on success and see if the controls reach there, because i use the same code to get current users id while logging into the application.

Another approach to find current users ID would be

var GUID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

This GUID Will be the aspnetusers ID that was generated while user registered.